# passing ruby arrays to javascript function from view page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How do I pass the ruby arrays to Js func and access it(from JS func)from a view page.. In my view page  I have defined an array as

```
<% asset_org.push({'url' => image_data['url'],
'height' => height_org,
'width'=> width_org                              
 }) %>
```

And I have passed this array as

```
<%= submit_tag "Create Slideshow",:Onclick=>"insert_slide(#{asset_org['height'].to_json}, #{asset_org['width'].to_json)" %>
```

But in the JS function(defined as function insert_slide(height, width)) of insert_slide I am not able to access this array of height and width

It is showing an error as asset_org is not defined... Any inputs on this??

Comment: how come you're getting the data as json? I'm not sure it matters but my first blush would have been to interpolate the straight value into the string you're building there...and where is asset_org defined?

Comment: so shoud I do convert it to string like <%= submit_tag "Create Slideshow",:Onclick=>{"insert_slide('#{params[:ed]}', '#{asset_org['height'].to_s}', '#{asset_org['width'].to_s}')"} %>

Comment: I am new to ruby on rails... So its a learning stage for me;)

Comment: Yeah, give that a try and let me know...and I don't think you need the single quotes around the javascript parameters...those are numbers, right? The basic rule of thumb here is that what you put in the :onclick value is going to be the string that the template puts down verbatim...

Answer (score 2):

Array's to_json() is a good way to pass the data if you can guarantee that the array 
doesn't contain any values that will cause to_json to raise exceptions.

Other than some scope issues you might be having (try using <%= debug asset_org %> in your view), you aren't accessing the array values properly in your submit_tag code.

Assuming your array only has one item, it should look like:

```
<%= submit_tag "Create Slideshow",
  :onclick=>"insert_slide('#{asset_org[0]['height']}', '#{asset_org[0]['width']}')" 
%>
```

Even better, modify insert_slide() to take an object parameter, then you could call it like this:

```
:onclick=>"insert_slide(#{asset_org[0]}.to_json)"
```